# Download files in queue in Android

Tags: android

How do I download multiple files in a queue one by one! I'm using [this](https://github.com/umeng/android_download_manager) as a sample code, since. 
I would be passing the URLs to download in Strings from my local DB dynamically.

Please let me know how to do that. I want the download to start as soon as the application launches. Kindly help me out!
**Android Dev Type**: Newbie
**Purpose of Download Queue:** To download multiple files from the server after in-app billing gets successful!

**P.S.:** I already referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336365/download-queue-in-android/4337002#4337002) question. But I'm not sure if that would solve my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way of queuing up requests to be handled asynchronously, one at a time, is with an `IntentService`. If you have an `IntentService` which reads URLs from the supplied `Intent`, then all you have to do is create an `Intent` for each file you want to download, and send each `Intent` to the service,

[Here is a good tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/).

**EDIT**: I see you've already referred to a similar question, where the answer recommends `IntentService`. So, maybe you should use an `IntentService`. :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Can you please have a look at the code I have referenced in my question (The Git code) and let me know where to use the IntentService Please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From API 11 up, a good approach is to use a FixedThreadPool with async tasks. Do once:

```
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

Where 3 is the number of downloads you want to run at the same time. It will queueu the task if there are already 3 downloads running, and automatically handle the task later. 
Launch your async tasks with:

```
yourAsynTask.executeOnExecutor(threadPoolExecutor, params);
```

Params is probably the url you wish to connect to. You can read it out in the onPostExecute of your asynctask, and connect to the server using a [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Make sure you call down this on shutdown:

```
threadPoolExecutor.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to implement a download queue in Android?

Use an `IntentService`. It supplies the queue and the background thread for you, so all you have to do is put your download logic in `onHandleIntent()`. [See here for a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/Downloader/) demonstrating this.