# Manage downloading queue in android

Tags: android, download, queue, message-queue

How to make a queue for downloading large images? I used `Service` for that. The queue is also dynamic. If user starts downloading for 3 images, I start my service for downloading 3 images. but user can add also more images for download but I have to add in queue and one by one download all images.

Can I use handler in `Service`? Can I use `handler.sendMessage(msg1)` and `handler.sendMessage(msg2)`? I don't know the method in handler `handleMessage(msg)` maintain queue smartly.

Is `msg1` and `msg2` handled simultaneously or in queue? If it is handled one by one then It solves my problem (means `msg2` is handled after completion of `msg1`).

Or is there any queue management process available?

Here is I want to make queue for downloading images and that downloaded image id i want to store, but if there is any queue that maintain some task,process then it will be great and smarty queue.

[Download files in queue in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323955/download-files-in-queue-in-android) did not give me satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

Handler itself manages queue of messages

This can use in `Service`.

I made sample.. I'm going to use custom processes in queue...
here is for download..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Message msg = h.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = 0;
    msg.obj = "url1";
    h.sendMessage(msg);

    Message msg1 = h.obtainMessage();
    msg1.what = 1;
    msg1.obj = "url2";
    h.sendMessage(msg1);

    Message msg2 = h.obtainMessage();
    msg2.what = 2;
    msg2.obj = "url2";
    h.sendMessage(msg2);

    Message msg3 = h.obtainMessage();
    msg3.what = 3;
    msg3.obj = "url3";
    h.sendMessage(msg3);
}

Handler h = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.e("", "handleMessage(msg) " + msg.what);
        download("" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "" + msg.obj);
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

private void download(String name, String link) {

    try {

        // Debug.e("", photo.imagename);
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                .execute(httpRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
        InputStream input = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

        File outPutFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outPutFile);

        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

        } finally {
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }

        // Toast.makeText(mContext, "Download completed",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // incrementCounter(Constant.ACTION_DOWNLOADS, photo.iid);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

Other best practices is welcomed...