# Check when a file has finished downloading in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, download

I am making an application where on clicking a button, the selected song list is to be downloaded and I need to begin downloading a file only when the file before it has completed downloading. Is there any way to confirm?

Comment: You should use transactions and async communication. In other way I could use simple queue with synchronized threads

Comment: Could you give me an example? Or a link? Would be helpful.

Comment: I think that Pshemo wrote a good answer, you can also look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323955/download-files-in-queue-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I am not Android or multi-threading expert so there may be better ways to do this, but from what I remember you could use Executors for this scenario, like

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);// allow only one task to run, 
                                                     // place rest of task in queue
es.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //download file one
    }
});
es.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //download file two
    }
});
```

Downloading file in second task will be executed only if code in previous task will finish.

Comment: Would it work if I out a loop around it?
Plus, I'll be opening a downloadable link. Hence the task is just to open the link via a browser or default set download manager.

Comment: @VirenChugh I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work, but as I said, I am not an Android expert. You will need to try it. Or maybe first take a look at link provided by @ MarcinErbel in comment under your question. That answer seems to be reasonable.

Comment: Tried it. I get the concept as well. Opens both links at one time. This is because my function does not download the file but just opens a link which triggers the downloading. Hence once that's done, it moves on to the next file. But this actually helps me out in another project, so thank you. :)